# How to pass the value of a dropdown to a powerapp flow

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

I would like to know how I can in powerapp pass the value of `SubCategoriesDropdown.SelectedText.EMAIL` to the flow that you see in the image. The idea would be to pass the value of the email in the part where it says `*A`

I would appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using powerApps trigger. If you click on 'add dynamic content' there's an option to ask in powerApps.